# How to use fotorama in Magento 2 as custom slider?

Tags: magento2, gallery, slider

I've tried to create a new fotorama thumbs slider for crosssells.
Therefor I used the

```
$block->getGalleryImagesJson()
```

for the initialization.
But then I tried to extend my product detail page with that javascript snippet from the gallery.phtml and that's it.
I now stuck from here and have no clue if that is possible to use fotorama only for thumbnail sliders.